# IE9 session cookie between HTTP and HTTPS is different

Tags: cookies, internet-explorer-9, sessionid

The following PHP code reproduces this problem.  In IE9 the session id being printed is different between HTTP and HTTPS.  In Chrome 16 and Firefox 8 the session id is the same between HTTP and HTTPS.

This is the exact same Web page.  Only difference is the protocol.

```
  1 <?
  2 session_start();
  3 
  4 $sid = session_id();
  5 
  6 print session_name() . ": " .$sid;
  7 
  8 ?>
```

The cookie is not set as secure.  IE9 seems to be managing a completely different pool of cookies for HTTPS than it is using for HTTP.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the security settings for IE were messed up - this website was put into some "trusted websites", so when I deleted those "trusted sites", reverted all security settings to default, set the Zone to Internet - problem got solved and session is now shared between http and https.
Seems like this is another one of those IE "features" - allowing you to completely mess up the Internet.

Comment: same problem! removing site from trusted sites resolved the issue for me. thank you!